# I have a PHP code which gives and error when executing. Can anyone point me out the error please.

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code.

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$user_name = "un";
$user_pass="123";  
$mysql_qry ="select * from user where username like '$user_name' and main_password '$user_pass';";
$result = mysql_query($mysql_qry, $conn);

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    echo "Login Success!";
}else{
    echo "Invalid Username or Password!";
}

?>
```

Error message is attached herewith. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsiJn.png)

Comment: There is an error with your sql. you will need to add this code to view the actual error https://pastebin.com/L6ezuMWy or see @Gulmuhammeds answer

Comment: Your SQL has a simple error. Also please learn how to use parameters or you will have a SQL injection vulnerability in your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Help: Warning: mysql\_num\_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273244/error-help-warning-mysql-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource)

Answer (score 2):

Please check your `$result` if it returns false and check your query error.

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if ($result==false)
{
    die(mysql_error());
}
else
{
    echo "Login Access";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Please check if you are able to connect to database or not (database name, username and password to connect to database is correct or not)
2. Check if table name `user` exists

Do share contents of `conn.php` if you are unable to resolve the issue

On a separate note

1. please use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` as it is deprecated
2. modify your query to: `$mysql_qry ="select * from user where username = '$user_name' and main_password '$user_pass';";` . `like` is a very expensive operation

Answer (score 0):

I think something wrong with your MySQL query function,
try using

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);
```

or

```
$result = mysql_query($mysql_qry);
```

instead of

```
$result = mysql_query($mysql_qry, $conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering how this point missed.. there is an error in your sql query. There is = or like operator missing after main_password. I would not recommend to check password in your query, you should fetch record with username and check password in if condition.

$mysql_qry ="select * from user where username like '$user_name' and main_password = '$user_pass'";

Hope this helps​.